# How to use mysql transaction within multiple related functions

Tags: node.js, mysql2

I am using `mysql2/promise`

This is **db.ts** which is used in all files

```
import mysql from "mysql2/promise";

const db = mysql.createPool({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "1_1_1",
});
export default db;
```

I have created a class of User

**User.ts**

```
import db from "../db";

const User = class {
  public userId: string;
  constructor(userId: string) {
    this.userId = userId;
  }

  public async initialize(): Promise<void> {
    const isUserId = await User.isUserId(this.userId);
    if (!isUserId) {
      throw new Error(`${this.userId} is not a valid user id`);
    }
  }

  public static async createInstance(userId: string) {
    const user = new User(userId);
    await user.initialize();
    return user;
  }

  public static async isUserId(userId: string): Promise<boolean> {
    const sql = `SELECT userId FROM ${userTbl} WHERE userId = ?`;
    const [rows]: any = await db.execute(sql, [userId]);
    return rows.length > 0 ? true : false;
  }
 
  ....
};
```

And i am registering users in **auth.ts**

```
import db from "../db";
import User from "../libs/User";

const Register = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const conn = await db.getConnection();
  try {
    await conn.beginTransaction();

    const { userName, firstName, lastName, mobileNumber, email, password } = req.body;

    const userId = await User.createNewUserId();
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    const userData = {
      userId,
      email,
      userName,
      firstName,
      lastName,
      mobileNumber,
      password: hashedPassword,
    };

    const sql = `INSERT INTO ${userTbl} SET ?`;
    await conn.query(sql, userData);

    // Here is the problem is throws error 
    const user = await User.createInstance(userId);

    await conn.commit();
    conn.release();
  } catch {
    await conn.rollback();
  }
};
```

The problem is in **User.ts** file method **isUserId** is returning false because it is using pool.query directly.

I have searched alot for this question but didn't found answer anywhere.

How can i use this in correct way? What will be the best practice to do this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using Class of DB

***db.ts***

```js
import mysql, { OkPacket, ResultSetHeader, RowDataPacket } from "mysql2/promise";

const config = {
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "1_1_1",
};

const DB = class {
  public static db: mysql.Connection;

  public static conn = async () => {
    if(DB.db) return DB.db;
    DB.db = await mysql.createConnection(config);
    return DB.db;
  };

  public static execute = async <
    T extends RowDataPacket[][] | RowDataPacket[] | OkPacket | OkPacket[] | ResultSetHeader
  >(
    sql: string,
    params?: Object | Array<string>
  ) => {
    const connection = await DB.conn();
    return await connection.execute<T>(sql, params);
  };

  public static query = async <
    T extends RowDataPacket[][] | RowDataPacket[] | OkPacket | OkPacket[] | ResultSetHeader
  >(
    sql: string,
    params?: Object | Array<string>
  ) => {
    const connection = await DB.conn();
    return await connection.query<T>(sql, params);
  };
};

export default DB;
```